# JSON Extract of a path with quotations

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, payload

I am working on BigQuery and need to extract from a payload the data of a path which has a word between quotations (ex. "Which is the 'store' name?")

What I am doing is this:

```
select JSON_extract(payload, "$.Which is the 'store' name?")
from data
```

The problem is that it returns: `Invalid token in JSONPath at: 'store'`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression instead as in below example

```
select 
  regexp_extract(payload, r'"Which is the \'store\' name\?":"([^"]*)"')
from your_table
```

Note - you should escape some chars like apostrophe, question marks in this case

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mikhail! What I really need is to get the value attached to that path. With your solution I easily get the path, but not the value. If you know a way it would be fantastic! Thank you again

Comment: have you actually tried? it returns value! not a path! please try again and let me know. if you still feel different  - provide better example that shows your real need :o)

Comment: You are right! Thank you!

Comment: Yes Mikhail! Thank you again